# Java EE 6 Tutorial Components are not available vie Update Center Tool

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am trying to download Java EE 6 Tutorial Components as described [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gexaj.html#gexba) using the Update Tool of Java EE 6 SDK (GlassFish Open Source Edition 3.1.1 Full Distribution). But I can not find "Java EE 6 Tutorial" check box in the list of Available Add-Ons. Any ideas why it is not available?

Is there any other sources to download directly the tutorial examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it!

Under "GlassFish 3" node in starting screen of the update tool you must select also "release.javaeesdk.oracle.com" software source which is unchecked by default (at least in my installation). Use the button "Edit properties".

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find it in Add-Ons, but found it under 'Available Updates'

Comment: In "Available Updates" I get "No updates are available" message which makes me thing that I got already tutorials examples installed. But I can not find them anyway in the installation directories of GlassFish.